# Magento 2.1 Multistore - Invoice not created

Tags: multistore, invoice, multicurrency, multidomain, create-invoice

I have **5 stores** (5 domains) running on **magento 2.1**
The last store I created doesn't create invoice after an order is completed
because of that the order confirmation email isn't sent to the customer.

Does anyone know why this is the case and how I can fix it?

FYI: I do use another currency here.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi ! Some more information will be helpful. Are you using any 3rd party module for generating invoice? Try to check logs , it may reveal some information which may help you fix it.

Comment: Hi! No, I am not using a 3rd party module for generating invoices. Im really at a loss here.. No Idea how to fix this..

Comment: Have you tried manually generating the invoice and checking your system/exception logs to make sure that no errors are being logged